# How to dynamically change pseudo-class value in css

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

Let's say I have a navigation panel `<div class="nav">..` with 5 `<a>` links.

```
CSS:
.nav a:nth-of-type(1) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I want to switch the underlined element by altering the CSS notation to:

```
CSS:
.nav a:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

### Is it possible? (proof of concept)

#### EDIT:

I don't understand why the downwote? It is normal, legitimate question about whether it is possible to change the part in front of {} brackets -> `change_this { stays_the_same }` somehow, possibly with javascript.

Comment: Seems like XY problem... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the CSS code using Javascript?  Is that right?

Comment: why not just  to switch class ?

Comment: Css within css files or <style> block are not meant to be modify dynamicaly. You'll have to use javascript.

Comment: I don't understand why the downwote? It is legitimate question asking if it is possible to change the part in front of `{ .. }` with javascript!

Comment: @eicto This question is not related to what am I actually doing, it is related to *if it is even possible*.

Comment: It's possible by just deleting the 1 and replacing it with a 2 in your CSS in your editor. It's not clear otherwise what you mean by "altering the CSS notation". Do you want to alter the stylesheet itself, or do you want it to happen at a certain time or after a certain event or trigger?

Comment: @elclanrs I am trying to change the part in front of brackets. I don't know how is it called, nor I am native english speaker to clearly explain myself, that's why I posted the example code.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, I posted the example code, so I wonder what's not clear. I just want to change the 1 to 2. I don't know how to describe it in another way, my english skills are limited. I just want to change the text of the css.
I want to click on the `<a>` element, which then changes the css `n-th-type(1)` to `n-th-type(2)`

Comment: @SuperScript Yes, I am trying to modify the code in whatever way it is possible. Javascript sounds good.

Comment: Use jquery where you can select `$(".nav a").eq(2).css("text-decoration","underline")`. You won't be directly changing the css in the file. That isn't possible. But you can apply inline css to the element you want, which has higher precedence over the file css.

Comment: @scrappedcola Thanks, I know about ways to do that and I have it working, I only wanted to know if there is different approach. The answer seems to be *NO*, you can't _change-this_ { .. }. If you want, I will accept your answer, just write it there :)). No is an answer after all too.

Comment: @elclanrs Now that I looked up what does _XY problem_ mean, I can assure you that I have a working solution, I was just curious if it is possible to _change-this_ { stays-same }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery where you can select `$(".nav a").eq(2).css("text-decoration","underline")`. You won't be directly changing the css in the file. That isn't possible. But you can apply inline css to the element you want, which has higher precedence over the file css

Answer (score -1):

You can use this structure

```
.nav a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: But this will underline all the `<a>` elements.